# Eclipse cannot run JUnit 5 test cases in JUnit suite?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, junit, testcase, test-suite

I've got working junit test cases I'd like to run in an Eclipse test suite. However, Eclipse only seems to have test suite support for JUnit 4 and 3.

It seems my options are to either either downgrade my test cases (which I'm unsure how to do) or upgrade the test suites as well (which I can't seem to find an option for).

Any help?

EDIT: For clarity, I'm working on the latest Eclipse Photon version, just downloaded it two days ago.

Comment: The current Eclipse Photon (4.8) ships with JUnit5 support, see https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_UI/JUnit_5#Eclipse_build_with_JUnit_5.0.0_GA_support: and https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/october/article5.php. Please include the Eclipse version you are on in the question.

Comment: @wwerner , I'm using exactly that version of Eclipse, sorry for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

With a plain Photon (Java Developers flavour) install, follow these steps to get a working simple eclipse project with a JUnit5 test and a suite containing this test.

- On project creation or in the project properties, add JUnit5 as library
  [image: Add JUnit library]
  [image: Select JUnit5]
- Add your tests, run them
  [image: Test & Test run]
- Add a test suite (the new Test Suite wizard is lacking the option to create a JUnit5 Suite, you'd need to write it by hand - was that what you were asking?)
  [image: Suite & Suite run]

Answer (score 1):

In package explorer, do right click on a project and,

- Click 'Build Path'
- Click 'Add Libraries'
- Click on 'JUnit 5' in the list and next, finish.

Then run the tests again.